syslinux.cfg ignores preseed/url on PXE boot
I'm trying to make a pxe-booted debian installer load a preseed file by default.  I've verified that the preseed file works because I can point the installer to it manually and the installation begins.
The following syslinux.cfg file does automatically select debian-netboot after booting over the network and I've verified that the initrd param is being read in the APPEND line because I can set the .gz file to a non-existent filename and it errors with the value I set in the file.
# D-I config version 2.0
# search path for the c32 support libraries (libcom32, libutil etc.)
path debian-installer/amd64/boot-screens/
prompt 0
timeout 0
include debian-installer/amd64/boot-screens/menu.cfg
# default debian-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
default debian-netboot

LABEL debian-netboot
  MENU LABEL Debian Netboot
  KERNEL debian-installer/amd64/linux
  APPEND vga=788 initrd=debian-installer/amd64/initrd.gz preseed/url=tftp://<tftp-server>/preseed ---

How do I make the installer use the preseed file?

The initrd.gz file is necessarily loaded by the bootloader (pxelinux in your case), but the preseed file is loaded by the installer in the initrd.gz file. You should increase the log level of your TFTP server or use e.g. tcpdump -Knpvv udp port tftp to view the actual TFTP requests and the server's responses and verify that the requested path actually refers to the correct file and the TFTP server will be able to read it.
